# VBA opens Outlook from a Watch window

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Recently I've stumbled upon a strange behaviour of VBA. In my Microsoft Excel Macro-Enabled Worksheet I have several sheets, with one named "Log". While I was debugging a code, I added a new watch with an expression `Worksheets("Log")`. When I click on the `+` box in front of it to expand the expression, `Welcome to Outlook 2016` wizard pops up?!

[image: Welcome to Outlook 2016]

On each subsequent click on the expression, `New Profile` window pops up.

[image: New Profile]

Funny thing is, I don't even use Outlook and it alone cannot be uninstalled from the system and rest of the Office package. So, what is happening here and how can I prevent this strange behaviour?

Comment: Up +1. Got the same issue.

Comment: Same issue here, trying to watch a class variable.

Comment: [Possible solution](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-vba-when-locals-are-expanded-outlook-starts/9325f17a-e3ad-4e00-8151-5cb60324ee6a)

Answer (score 0):

I have it too, also when I have the watch set to a page of the worksheet.
It seems to happen when I forget to activate the sheet before I access it. After doing that the Macro and watch behave as expected.